# SQL Insert data into multiple tables from data table that contains table name, column name and value column mapping can change in source

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pentaho

I am perplexed. This looks possible but unsure how to accomplish this.
I have a data table that looks like this. The data source will sometimes
swap columns in the source file.

```
Data                            
    IN      column          table_sheet          y      w       value   
    col1    Route           Summary              2021   Week 1  a   
    col2    CNG/Diesel      Summary              2021   Week 1  5           
    col3    Freq            Summary              2021   Week 1  B       
    col4    Weekly Miles    Summary              2021   Week 1  6       
    col1    CNG/Diesel      Summary              2021   Week 2  1       
    col2    Freq            Summary              2021   Week 3  1       
    col3    Weekly Miles    Summary              2021   Week 4  1       
    col1    Load            Days_ON              2021   Week 1  L210224-25048   
    col2    Load_id         Days_ON              2021   Week 1  L210224-25048
    col3    cost            Days_ON              2021   Week 1  263.64  
    col1    Distance        CCD                  2021   Week 2  781.62      
    col2    Code            CCD                  2021   Week 2  CL      
    col3    Name            CCD                  2021   Week 2  Squre       
    col4    Cost            CCD                  2021   Week 2  1800
```

The source file is a spreadsheet with multiple sheets (Table name for the project) that is populated weekly and is incremental.
The source file column mapping can change as in table Summary, all columns(excel source file column index) from the source changed . The destination tables have all possible column names already in place. The SQL code must read the table name and map the data to the source table accordingly.

```
I want to populate the below tables using the data table above like this.               
Summary     Route    CNG/Diesel Freq    Weekly Miles    y       W
            a        5          B       6               2021    Week 1
                     1                                  2021    Week 2
                                1                       2021    Week 3
                                        1               2021    Week 4
                            
Days_ON                 
        Load            LoaD_id         cost    y          W
        L210224-25048   L210224-25048   263.64  2021       Week 1   
                            
                            
CCD                         
        Distance        Code    Name        Cost    y       W
        781.62          CL      Squre       1800    2021    Week 1
```

ADDED-
The solution may work for one row but it is not working for multiple rows in same week.

```html
Data                
IN      column           table_sheet     y      w     value h1_ind
    col1    Route        Summary        2021    Week 1  a   2
    col2    CNG/Diesel   Summary        2021    Week 1  5   3
    col3    Freq         Summary        2021    Week 1  B   4
    col4    Weekly Miles Summary        2021    Week 1  6   5
    col1    Route        Summary        2021    Week 1  b   2
    col2    CNG/Diesel   Summary        2021    Week 1  1   3
    col3    Freq         Summary        2021    Week 1  1   4
    col4    Weekly Miles Summary        2021    Week 1  1   5
    col1    Route        Summary        2021    Week 1  c   2
    col2    CNG/Diesel   Summary        2021    Week 1  5   3
    col3    Freq         Summary        2021    Week 1  B   4
    col4    Weekly Miles Summary        2021    Week 1  6   5
    col1    Route        Summary        2021    Week 1  d   2
    col2    CNG/Diesel   Summary        2021    Week 1  1   3
    col3    Freq         Summary        2021    Week 1  1   4
    col4    Weekly Miles Summary        2021    Week 1  1   5

Desired output:
table_sheet    y      w      Route CNG/Diesel  Freq  Weekly Miles
Summary       2021   Week 1   a       5         B     6
Summary       2021   Week 1   b       1         1     1
Summary       2021   Week 1   c       5         B     6
Summary       2021   Week 1   d       1         1     1
```

If possible how could SQL unpivot provide this output? I would like to see this.
I would also like to see if we can get spoon to work.
Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to separate your rows by table_sheet and afterwards apply a Row denormaliser for each table_sheet, because your producing different tables:
[image: Transformation to create]

[image: How you parametrize the Switch/case step]

[image: How you parametrize the Row denormaliser step]

Comment: This does not work for multiple rows: see Above - ADDED - please help

Comment: OK, this doesn't work because you don't have a "unique key" to denormalise the table, what you want to achieve will only work if you receive (and read) the rows in order, if you get the rows mixed it won't work. If the rows are ordered, you can add a counter that only changes when you get a new value of table_sheet, y, w and Route, but stays the same with the rest of the CNG, Freq, and Weekly Miles, it will need some complex logic to add it. Once you have it, you add the counter to the Group field in the denormaliser step.